# EasyMock Testing Void With Runnable

Tags: testing, easymock

I'm trying to test the following class (I've left out the implementation)

```
public class UTRI implements UTR {
    public void runAsUser(String userId, Runnable r);
}
```

This is the way I would use it:

```
UTRI.runAsUser("User1", new Runnable () {
    private void run() {
    //do whatever needs to be done here.

    }
});
```

The problem is, I don't know how to use EasyMock to test functions that return void.  That and I'm also not too familiar with testing in general (right out of school!).  Can someone help explain to me what I need to do to approach this?  I was thinking about making the UTRI a mock and doing expectlastcall after that, but realistically, not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class UTRITest {

    UTRI utri = new UTRI();

    @Test
    public void testRunAsUser() {
        // Create Mocks
        Runnable mockRunnable = EasyMock.createMock(Runnable.class);

        // Set Expectations
        **mockRunnable.run();
        EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();**

        EasyMock.replay(mockRunnable);
        // Call the method under test
        utri.runAsUser("RAMBO", **mockRunnable**);

        // Verify if run was called on Runnable!!
        EasyMock.verify(mockRunnable);
    }    
}
```